# What mechanism is the "1 to 10 method call" called in scala?

Tags: scala

I am a beginner in scala. I found that method call `(1).to(10)` can be written as `1 to 10` for simple in scala. This is very interesting. So I have some questions about this:

1. What does this mechanism call? Or it's just a syntactic sugar?
2. If I'd like to call the two parameters `def to(end: Int, step: Int): Inclusive` method in RichInt, can I write as `1 to 10, 1`(not work, just took for example) or something else?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This mechanism is called "infix notation". Details can be found in [Scala doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)
2. Methods which take more than one parameter could still be invoked using infix notation, delimited by spaces, such as `1 to (10,2)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "infix notation". The `def to(end: Int, step: Int): Inclusive` method can be invoked with `1 to (end, step)`. However, the `Range` returned by `1 to 10` has a `by` method, which can be used to accomplish the same thing: `1 to 10 by 2`, which is equivalent to `1.to(10).by(2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then what could I write if I want to loop from 10 to 1?

Comment: `(1 to 10).reverse` will return a new range in reversed order.

Comment: Thx. What' more, I just found that methods which take more than one parameter could still be invoked using infix notation, delimited by spaces, such as `1 to (10,2)`.